# NGINX does not set X-Forwarded-For properly

Tags: node.js, http, nginx, ip, x-forwarded-for

I have an NGINX server acting as a load-balancer for several other servers. Since I need access to the user's IP address, I added the following lines to my nginx configuration:

```
 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Then, in the backend servers, I simply use the first IP address in the X-Forwarded-For header. However, every few minutes (once every ~2K requests), I get `unknown, xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` as the value of the header, where `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` is an IP address (a different one every time). What could be the source of this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#var_proxy_add_x_forwarded_for), The `$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for` variable consists of:

> the “X-Forwarded-For” client request header field with the
>   $remote_addr variable appended to it, separated by a comma.
>
> If the “X-Forwarded-For” field is not present in the client request
>   header, the $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for variable is equal to the
>   $remote_addr variable.

From this we can conclude that `nginx` received a request from some remote client (possibly a forward proxy) with a request header of:

```
X-Forwarded-For: unknown
```